# How to translate if .. else statement with goto?

Tags: c, if-statement, goto

I have to translate nested-if..else conditions to goto labels in C code. 
I know that I have to start with outer if-s, but how to translate the inner if-s with goto?

```
Example: if(condition)
          {
            if(condition)
            {
             if(condition)
              {
                statements;
              }
              if(condition) return;
              statements;
            }  
          }
        else statements;
```

Comment: Create sequences of code corresponding to every block in your original program.  Label them.  Insert `goto` statements to connect them.  It just takes elementary reasoning.

Comment: `if (X) { statements A } else { statements B }` can be rewritten `if (X) goto A; { statements B } goto E; A: { statements A } E: ;`  By substitution (just as in high school algebra), you can get the answer from this. Just substitute a single if-then-else at a time.

Comment: why? it will make things messy.

Comment: It is not logical to use go to. However, somehow you need to compare the or check the values. You can use the ’?’ for that, and label the lines like 'A:' then use goto A

Comment: If you want to create if else chain in very low level u must use assembly

Comment: I have to use goto because this is my task to translate the if-conditions into goto. Assembly I will use, when I`m done with translation. All of this is with reason. 

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually, You do not need to translate `Ìf statement` or any statement that belongs to `C`.
You could use directly like this, it will automatically translate into `Assembly`

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char SerData = 0x44;
    unsigned char TempSerData;
    unsigned char x;
    TempSerData = SerData;
    DDRC |= (1<<SerPin); //configure PORT C pin3 as output
    for (x=0;x<8;x++)
    {
       if (TempSerData & 0x01) // check least significant bit
             PORTC |= (1<<serPin); // set PORT C pin 3 to 1
       else
          PORTC &= ~(1<<serPin); // set PORT C pin 3 to 0
       TempSerData = TempSerData >> 1; // shift to check the next bit
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, If you wanted to translate `if`, you could use something like this, but as I said yo do not need to convert it, or you do not need `C` for this job.

```
int x = 0, y = 1;
(x >= y) ? goto A: goto B
A: // code goes here 
    goto end
B: // code goes here  
    goto end
end: return 0;
```

In assembly, you can do it very easily. For example, in `Àtmega128`:

```
ldi r16, 0x00 ; load register 16 with 0
ldi r17, 0x01 ; load register 17 with 1

sub r17, r16  ; take the difference
brcs if_label
else_label:             ; do some operation on that line or on the other lines
          rjmp end
if_label:               ; do some operation on that line or on the other lines     
end: rjmp end           ; program finishes here
```

Comment: You cannot use `goto` as part of the conditional operator.

Comment: one of the online compiler let me to do it, so i thought i could use it @pmg

Comment: Can you share what online compiler allows `goto` statements inside the conditional operator? Thanks